# How to install windows 10 client in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

How to install windows 10 client in google cloud? Because I only can choose windows server from the list.

Comment: I want to have Windows 10 as Desktop as a Service in Google cloud, however I cannot find the windows 10 when I try to create VM in google cloud. Do you know how to install manually windows 10 in google cloud?

Comment: It's useful if you need a remote machine used to administer stuff. The windows server license is NOT cheap

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this does not seem to be a use case that Google has catered for. I too have a need to have a cloud desktop that I can access anywhere. There are two clear use cases for this

1. where you need to create a true virtual desktop that you can access from
   anywhere, including a client site, airport, etc
2. for creating test environments
   where you need to test an app on something other than a (costly)
   windows server instance.

The Google compute engine looks to be designed for servers / services only. Think the easiest option for now is to do it in Azure where spinning up test or other desktops is recognised as a valid use case.

Comment: 3rd case: Instead of using a VPN use a VM

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an option now.  However, you must provide your own Windows license and import your image as a virtual disk.

See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/#windows_client for more information.

Comment: Yes, but only for sole-tentant nodes that are significantly more expensive than regular nodes.